# JSP cannot find symbol ClassName

Tags: java, jsp

It is a JSP application. Under /WEB-INF/src I have A.java and B.java, both in package p.

Class A uses B. B compiled through but when compiling A, it says Cannot find symbol B.

B.class can be found at /WEB-INF/classes/p/B.class.

One more thing worth mention, at the beginning both A and B are in default package and there was no problem in compilation with either class.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to Jigar I tried javac -classpath ../classes -d.....and it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems with classpath , you need to add  proper `-classpath` switch to `javac`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your log didn't show any errors?  Sometimes a cannot find symbol can result from an exception in some static variables of the class.  If static initialization fails, the class doesn't load and other classes can't use it.

The top of both A.java and B.java have `package p;`, right?  And exist in folder "p"?

Maybe you can post some code if still not working.